# Issues with finding objects queried with HQL or session filter in Hibernate 4 + Spring 4 + JTA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, upgrade, jta

We recently migrated from Hibernate 3.2.3, Spring 3.2.2 to Hibernate 4.3.11 and Spring 4.2.1 on Weblogic 10.3

Now in a transaction when hibernate objects are created and added to a hibernate object's  persistent collection and later queried with HQL(using hibernateTemplate) or Hibernate's "Query" feature (in the same transaction and before the end of the transaction), Hibernate fails to find the objects that were added. This worked with Hibernate 3 and Spring 3 before the upgrade, but now fails.

e.g. In Psuedo code, say i have a library class with the following property.

```
class Library{
   private Collection<Books> books;
}
```

In a transaction, i do the following -

```
...
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setAuthor("Patrick Holt");
library.getBooks().add(book1);
```

and later on in the same transaction, Hibernate's "Query" is used with a Filter to look for  books by the author, like so

```
Session s = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query q = s.createFilter(library.getBooks(), "where this.author =  :authorName");
q.setParameter("authorName", "Patrick Holt");
List l = q.list();
```

q.list() in the above example returns 0 results. This would return 1 result before the upgrade. After the upgrade i get 0 results.

I read about some changes in the currentSessionContext in upgrades to Hibernate 4 and Spring 4, but I'm not sure what needs to change in order for the behavior to be just like before the upgrade, without the code having to change.

Out hibernate objects are defined in hbm.xml files and here's my configuration of the session factory.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <!--
                Tried adding the following properties, but it didn't work either
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingJarLocations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/lib/app-1.0.jar</value>
            </list>
        </property>
     </bean>
```

Transaction Manager definition:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"/>
```

The datasource is made available over jndi.

Any ideas on what i need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: when you do the `library.getBooks().add(book1);` in your example . is hibernate configured with auto-flush ? can you see an insert query at that time or it waits for a commit on the whole transaction? also , you could check what entities are in the cache , because even if you dont see an insert query , at least it should have been in the second level cache. And a last question , i suppose that you are doing the 2 operations in the same thread , sequentially ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev - I haven't configured Hibernate explicitly anywhere. I'm guessing when in a transaction the FlushMode is AUTO. I even tried explicitly setting the FlushMode on the query to be ALWAYS with no difference in results.
This is a problem even when the second level cache has been disabled. When book1 is added to the collection i do not see an insert statement (I do see a select with a join on Library and books - probably loading books).
Yes, both operations are in the same thread and actually in the same class, and in the same transaction.

Comment: ok cool , just a simple proposal , could you change your select statement and write a simple select by ID(looks like authorName is not a key) , and put just for test , the ID of the entity you ve created on the same transaction. Also when you say you updated from Hibernate 3 to 4 , you simply changed your maven dependencies, or did you change any configuration classes apart from the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` ; check this post it might be useful http://koenserneels.blogspot.gr/2012/05/migrating-from-hibernate-3-to-4-with.html

Comment: @AntJavaDev The issue seems to be that Hibernate's AUTO flushmode doesn't work in the transaction. The issue i am having is exactly the same as described in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13848.
I had already read and tried the suggestions in the blog you linked to, but there is no difference in behavior. 
The upgrade involved changing other spring related classes to match Hibernate4 e.g. hibernateTemplate,OpenSessionInViewFilter - If that's what you are asking. Some Hibernate props -  like the lookup for transaction manager - were removed in the newer version as they don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i was having is exactly as described in [Spring Jira Issue SPR-13848](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13848). As i understand, it seems like the OpenSessionInViewFilter opens a request scoped session early and there are issues with syncing with a transaction that's started later.

I could not get rid of my OSIV because of the impact that it would cause throughout my application. 
However, i found out that hibernate has a property that will accomplish something similar to prevent lazy loading -

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```

This solved the issue. Adding this property allowed me to remove the OSIV, and hibernate's AUTO flush mode works as expected in a transaction now. I also used the CMTTransactionFactory. All my hibernate properties:

```
             <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
            </props>
```